# Force Cmake & Emscripten to use VS 2010 for compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, llvm, emscripten

How can I force Cmake to use Visual Studio 2010 for compiling my emscripten projects, and now VS 2015?

[image]

I keep running into an issue where cmake says it cannot find the build tools for MSBuild v140. I know it exists though, as the file path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
```

I've even tried setting the path in the Emscripten Command Prompt with

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;%PATH%
```

but the issue still occurs.

[image]

If I open this solution in VS 2015, I can see that the configuration is set to Msbuild v 1.40, so I can't wrap my head around why Emscripten says it can't locate it.

The closest thing I could find is in [this GitHub bug report on Emscripten.](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/3814)

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you could specify the generator to CMake you should be able to select "Visual Studio 10 2010". Looking at the project on github and your output I do not see how CMake is being invoked so I can not really help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Emscripten in Visual Studio is only supported for VS2010 AFAIK. Personally, I suggest you work with makefiles when generating from CMake. It is much more stable from my experience. The Visual Studio support for Emscripten is not working well, at least for me.

But if you still want to use VS2010, then you have to set the CMake generator to "Visual Studio 10 2010", and then specify the Emscripten toolchain file. You might have to set the CMake platform name to Emscripten, using the -A argument.

```
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 10 2010" -A Emscripten -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%EMSCRIPTEN%\cmake\Modules\Platform\Emscripten.cmake
```

Comment: I'm fine with using anything that works. I am running Win 10 on a Mac Book Pro, so I could even use OSX for this, but I'd prefer to stick with Windows as my development envionrment, if possible. 

I'm just going through the lessons on the Emscripten site now. 

Let me try this in Emscripten now and then I'll come back with my results!

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this, but each time I did, Emscripten would return a different path to Emscripten.cmake, and say it couldn't find it. Not sure where it was getting this new path from.

Long story short, I realized I installed the web installer for Emscripten installed. So I uninstalled that and instead went with the Full installer, and it all worked well.